# Python: Credit Card digits verification

Tags: python

I need to implement a function called “verify” that takes a single parameter called “number” and then checks the following rules:

1. The first digit must be a 4.
2. The fourth digit must be one greater than the fifth digit; keep in mind that these are separated by a dash since the format is ####-####-####.
3. The sum of all digits must be evenly divisible by 4.
   4 If you treat the first two digits as a two-digit number, and the seventh and eighth digits as a two-digit number, their sum must be 100
   This is what I have come up with so far:

```
  def verify(number) : # do not change this line!

    # write your code here so that it verifies the card number
    number_string = number.replace("-","")
    cardnumber = [int(n) for n in number_string]

    if cardnumber[0] != 4:
      return 1

    elif cardnumber[3] != cardnumber[4] + 1: 
      return 2

    elif sum(map(int, cardnumber)) % 4 != 0:
      return 3

    elif cardnumber[0:2] + cardnumber[6:8] != 100:
      return 4

    return True
    # be sure to indent your code!

    input = "4002-1001-0000" # change this as you test your function
    output = verify(input) # invoke the method using a test input
    print(output) # prints the output of the function
    # do not remove this line!
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have forgotten that you already converted `cardnumber` to a list of integers.  It's not a string any more, so you don't need to use `int` each and every time.  To compute your sums, you just need `cardnumber[0]*10+cardnumber[1]` and `cardnumber[7]*10+cardnumber[8]`.

Comment: What about the other restrictions, such the first digit must be a four, and digits 4/5 are separated by one step?

Comment: He already has those.  He can remove the `int` calls, but the code is already there.

Answer (score 0):

`cardnumber` is a list. A list can not be converted to an integer. To do so, you first need to convert the list to a string and to integer or directly to an integer using some logic.

**using string to integer logic**

```py
elif int(''.join(cardnum[0:2])) + int(''.join(cardnum[7:9])) != 100:
```